# How to call load() on a sucess request

Tags: ajax, jsp

I’m trying to call load() on success with ajax. I have to use load for this because it’s coming from another endpoint. However I am getting an error in the console that says Uncaught Error: only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed if i do this.

```
  .ajax({

  url : url,

  type : 'GET',

  dataType : "json",

  success : function(data) {

$.each(

//conditional statement

.load()
//other data being appended in.
```

is there anyway to call load on a success request under a conditional statement? i know there is a callback way but it can only do so On Success I need to call it under the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Put Alert Message `Alert(JSON.Stringfy(data))` and check
and

later u can use `window.onload`

OR

`document.getElementById("myFrame").addEventListener("load", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
    //write your own code
}`